# Copy worker's data to another worker without copying to the main app, is it possible at all?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Actually, I've read all available information on messageChannels related to web workers, but... unfortunately, I can't even understand whether this problem can be solved at all: I just want to copy the first worker's data to another worker **WITHOUT** sending it to the application page.

**workerA.js:**

```
var arrA = [];  
//what should I do to get arrA = ["A"]?
```

**workerB.js:**

```
var arrB = ["A", "B"];
//Let's say I want to push arrB[0] to var arrA in workerA.js...
//Again, there should not be any copy to the application page!
```

Is it possible? If yes, can anyone provide a working demo?